# existence of random variables having a specific joint law

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let us fix a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ supporting a random variable $X$, where the $\sigma$-filed $\mathcal F=\sigma(X)$.   For a sub-$\sigma$-filed $\mathcal G\subset\mathcal F$, we can define a new random vairable $Y=\mathbb E(X|\mathcal G)$. The joint law of $(X,Y)$, denoted $\pi$, would be a probability measure on $\mathbb R^2$, which satisfies

1. $\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x) d\pi(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)d\mu(x)$ for all bounded measurable function $f$, where $\mu$ is the law of $X$, and
2. $\int_{\mathbb R^2} g(y)(y-x)d\pi(x,y)=0$ for all bounded measurable function $g$.

Condition (1) says that the 1st marginal of $\pi$ is $\mu$, while condition (2) is equivalent to saying that the 1st and 2nd marginal of $\pi$ are related by a conditional expectation relation: $\mathbb E(X|Y)=Y$.

**What I want wo know is whether the converse of the above is true**: if a probability measure $\pi$ on $\mathbb R^2$ satisfying (1) and (2) is given, can I find a random variable $Y$ s.t. $(X,Y)$ has joint distribution $\pi$?